# Convert json &amp; to & in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an HTML element that have value attribute. The value should be Comfort & Protection but the name that comes from the JSON get result is Comfort `&amp;` Protection and AngularJS is printing it like this on my view.

I try to put this name inside an html element value attribute.

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-repeat="type in types" value="{{type.name}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.types = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Comfort &amp; Protection'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Other Name'
        }
    ]
})
```

http://codepen.io/Fclaussen/pen/vOXNbg

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should generally try to get the JSON to return rate data instead of HTML formatted data. It's less trouble to convert to HTML when you need HTML then to go the other way.

Comment: I have no control over what the api returns. I'm fetching from wp-api

Comment: Code example does not work, can you check it?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't see the input name with &amp; on the example?

Comment: The link is working fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to replace the `&amp;` string with `&` as below:

```
var text = name.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
```

Comment: I appreciate it, I managed to solve the problem based on your answer. Your answer is right, but it is just javascript. I had to apply it to angular. That's why I created a filter.

Comment: In my case, used `name.replace("\u0026amp;","&")`

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve the problem based on Max Zoom answer.

I created a filter to filter ampersands, like this.

```
app.filter('ampersand', function(){
    return function(input){
        return input ? input.replace(/&amp;/, '&') : '';
    }
});
```

And on my View I changed from `{{term.name}}` to `{{term.name | ampersand}}`