# Reddit API: How do I convert &amp; to & in Angular/Typescript/Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I cloned this repo: https://github.com/smartapant/ionic2-reddit-reader

It reads Reddit, but returns `&` as `&amp`;

This function returns new Reddit posts:

```
 load(url?) {
        this.redditApi.fetch(url).subscribe((posts) => {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.loadCompleted = true;
        console.log(posts)
      })
    }
```

I changed it to:

```
  load(url?) {
        this.redditApi.fetch(url).subscribe((posts) => {
        this.posts = posts;
        function replace() {
            var postscleaned =  posts.replace( /&amp;/g, '&' );
            return(postscleaned);
    };
        this.loadCompleted = true;
        console.log(postscleaned)
      })
    }
```

... following the advice in these questions:

[Decode &amp; back to & in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript)

[Convert json &amp; to & in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355025/convert-json-amp-to-in-angularjs/30355466)

And added  `postscleaned: Array<any>` to the export class PostsPage.

It builds alright, but I get a Typescript Error
`Cannot find name 'postscleaned'.`

What is the best way to solve this? Is there a method that will work in Typescript but not Javascript?

Comment: Functions introduce a new scope. Also please do not use `Array<any>`

Comment: What should I use instead of `Array<any>?`?

Comment: Let the type be inferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reddit API documentation:

**response body encoding**

For legacy reasons, all JSON response bodies currently have `<`, `>`, and `&`replaced with `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`, respectively. If you wish to opt out of this behaviour, add a raw_json=1 parameter to your request.

So:

www.reddit.com/r/longevity.json?

becomes

www.reddit.com/r/longevity.json?raw_json=1

& (ampersands) now display correctly. I don't know if there are any performance drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
function replace() {...};
```

You are defining a function, but not executing it. I am guessing what you really want to achieve is to execute those two lines:

```
var postscleaned =  posts.replace( /&amp;/g, '&' );
return(postscleaned);
```

instead of just giving them a name as a function.

In other words, the code you're looking for is:

```
load(url?) {
    this.redditApi.fetch(url).subscribe((posts) => {
    this.posts = posts;
    var postscleaned =  posts.replace( /&amp;/g, '&' );
    this.loadCompleted = true;
    console.log(postscleaned)
  })
}
```

However, posts seems like an array of strings rather than a single string, therefor what you *really* are looking for might be:

```
load(url?) {
    this.redditApi.fetch(url).subscribe((posts) => {
    this.posts = posts;
    var postscleaned = [];
    for (int i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
      postscleaned[i] = posts[i].replace( /&amp;/g, '&' );
    }
    this.loadCompleted = true;
    console.log(postscleaned)
  })
}
```

Comment: I will take a look at that and see if it works, thanks.

Comment: It returns: `"Runtime Error" posts.replace is not a function.` I tried    `var postscleaned =  posts.replace( /&amp;/g, '&' );` on its own without a function earlier. I wonder if it's a Typescript problem, because Javascript should recognize the replace method. Maybe I need to define the function elsewhere, then execute it.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) page to learn about how the replace function for strings works. The key word here is _strings_, which means that `posts` is not a string. (perhaps an array of strings? In which case, you need to wrap that replace statement in a for loop that iterates over `posts[i].replace(...);`.)

Comment: Posts is not a string, right. I could try a for loop iterating over an array. That makes sense.

Comment: Glad it does. I've updated the answer. Please accept it if it did indeed solve your problem. Thanks!

Comment: The for loop threw Typescript errors like "Expected ;". I changed it to a forEach loop, that passes webpack and Typescript error checks, but doesn't work fully yet. If I get the exact answer, I'll post it and credit you.