# Use ng-show to replace a character in a string

Tags: angularjs

**Problem:** I would like to be able to replace & amp; with & by using ng-show.

So I have a angular expression "e.Example" that contains the following strings {Camp & Stuff, Stuff $ Camp}. When I generate the string in my form, it represents "&" as "& amp;" and so forth.

I would like to be do something like:

```
<span ng-show="e.Example ==='$' replace it with someting else"></span>
```

How can I achieve that using ng-show? I know in C# I can use .Contains and .Replace. I was wondering if their is something similar in angularjs

@Lansana

I tried the following:

```
<span ng-show="e.Specialty === '&amp;' && doSomethingTo(e.Specialty)"></span>
```

However, when I look at debugger, it shows the & char and not '& amp;' which the '&' appears when I click sumbit and display results

**Update:** Tried the following:

```
    <span ng-show="doSomethingTo()"></span>

       function doSomethingTo(val){
           val.property = '&';
           return true;
       }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `ng-bind-html` ?

Comment: @CodeSpark yes, I have use ng-bind-html and ngSanitize and it does not work for me. it crashes. So I am wondering if I can do something with ng-show

Comment: @CodeSpark: Is it possible?

Comment: I think following link can help you out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355025/convert-json-amp-to-in-angularjs

Comment: @CodeSpark: I tried the following {{e.Specialty | ampersand}} and for the script:   app.filter('ampersand', function(){
    return function(e){
        return e ? e.replace(/&amp;/, '&') : '';
    }
});

Comment: @CodeSpark:  I am not sure what to replace the input. My guess would be the span tag or would it be at the form when the user selects which one to use

Comment: This is the third time today you've asked this duplicate question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120419/how-to-use-sanitize-on-html-entity

Comment: @Robert please stop asking duplicate questions.  Edit your existing questions instead.  And please stop thanking me for moderating your questions while ignoring everything said.

Comment: @Amy Not. Different Questions. Was curious if it couldnt be achieve using ng-bind-html, if I could try ng-show. and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Use the double ampersand comparison operators. If the first statement is true, the second will be executed.

Like so:

```
<span ng-show="e.Example ==='$' && doSomethingTo(e.Example)"></span>

function doSomethingTo(val) {
    val.property = 'foo';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @ Lansana: how would that work with html entity '&amp;'. The browser renders it as & in the debugger

Comment: You can escape the & using a backslash \.

Comment: Sorry, english not first language, what you mean escape the & using a backslash

Comment: If you have 3 &'s and the browser is trying to parse the 3rd &, you need to escape the 3rd & which tells the browser to ignore it. For example, browser will see this as 3 &'s: `&&&`. Browser will see this as only 2 &'s: `&&\&`, because the 3rd is escaped.

Comment: sorry um... I posted on what I mean

Comment: Can you try `\&amp;` instead of `&amp;`?

Comment: If that doesn't work, instead of doing the check you are . doing just put all of the logic into a function and simply do `<span ng-show="func(e)"></span>` which will both check the value as well as modify it and return true if all is well. At the javascript level, you won't have to worry about escaping the `&amp;`; that should only matter at the HTML level since the browser will automatically try to encode that.

Comment: @ Lansana: Tried that approach. Nothing seems to work. I will keep looking. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet right here.

Take a look to see if you're doing something wrong when using `ng-bind-html` with `$sce.trustAsHtml` function.

```js
(function() {

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('TestController', function($sce, $scope) {
      // Inject $sce service and call trust as html function
      $scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml("Camp &amp; Stuff, Stuff $ Camp");
      
    });

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
  
  <!-- Add ng-bind-html with the variable that contains the ampersand problem -->
  <span ng-bind-html="test"></span>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ Bruno: I see what you are doing. However, how would I do that on a angular expression? Also, ampersand is displayed as & in the table, not as &amp;. So when I display the results, instead of showing &, it displays &amp;